# Cell Data not showing properly in table view swif4

Tags: swift4.1

I am using table view inside table view I have used some views and then I used cell but when i running in simulator its content not showing properly 
I added screenshot please check it.

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return tc_array.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    print(b_description.bounds.size.height)
    return 200 + b_description.bounds.size.height

    // return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell : TermCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TermCell", for : indexPath as IndexPath) as! TermCell

     cell.tc_lebel.text! = tc_array[indexPath.row]

     print(cell.tc_lebel.text!)

     return cell
}
```

[new image click on it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1W2u2.png)
  [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1W2u2.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lwd8o.png . check it new image

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9rYO.png constraint image

Comment: Can you add some code and some screenshots please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have placed your constraints correctly, I would suggest removing

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{

    print(b_description.bounds.size.height)
    return 200 + b_description.bounds.size.height
}
```

And when you setup your view, in **viewDidLoad** you should add this for automatic row dimension

```
 tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
 tableView.estimatedRowHeight = yourAverageCellRowHeight
```

Comment: add a screen of your table view cell

Comment: I have added new image please check it @DionizB

Comment: I added Constraint image as well as @DionizB

Comment: You need to make sure that vertical constraints are all set, in every table view cell, also you have set constraints for your table view controller. In the screen you posted there, your view constraints inside table View Cell look ok.